# How to Pass View Constructor Parameter to View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a View and ViewModel.

```
MyView
{
  MyView(int id)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}

 MyViewModel
    {
     private int _id;
      public int ID
       {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id= value; OnPropertyChanged("_id"); }
       }
    }
```

I am setting the data Context on my XAML as :

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

On Click of a button I am showing my View as :

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => new MyView(id).Show());
```

Now , How do I pass id from `MyView(id)` to `MyViewModel.ID.`

Comment: Set the DataContext in code instead of XAML: `DataContext = new MyViewModel { ID = id };`

Comment: But I want to minimize usage of code behind as much as possible.

Comment: That isn't MVVM.  That's cargo cult.  Codebehind is perfectly fine for UI concerns.  It just shouldn't be used for BI.  (Just noticed--hello again! Not trolling your q's, I'm just going through my MVVM RSS feed)

Comment: A bit off topic, but use `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyProperty))` it'll make your life easier if you need to change any of the prop names later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the DataContext gets created after the InitializeComponent() call, you can just pass it to the ViewModel afterwards:

```
MyView
{
   MyView(int id)
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     ((MyViewModel)DataContext).ID = id;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do one of the following solutions :

**1) Use the `Messenger` pattern :**

You can use the Messenger Pattern, if you are using `MVVMLight` for example, you can do the following :

In the `ViewModel` do :

```
MyViewModel
{
     private int _id;
     public int ID
     {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id= value; OnPropertyChanged("_id"); }
     }

     Public void InitilizeMessenger()
     {
         Messenger.Default.Register(this,"To MyViewModel", (int id) => ID = id);
     }
     public MyViewModel()
     {
        InitilizeMessenger();
     }
}
```

You make the ViewModel ready for receiving messages by registering to the Messenger.

in the View do :

```
MyView
{
  MyView(int id)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Messenger.Default.Send<int>(id,"To MyViewModel");
  }
}
```

Broadcast a message, by sending it accompanied by the "To MyViewModel" tag, so it can be caught by the MyViewModel.

**2) Access DataContext from the View :**

```
MyView
{
  MyView(int id)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    ((MyViewModel)this.DataContext).ID = id;
  }
}
```

The second solution is straightforward and simpler, I gave the first one just for in case of more complicated scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,
OnPropertyChanged("_id") is wrong, beacuse _id is a variable, not a property. You must change as OnPropertyChanged("ID"). You can assign viewModel in code behind.

```
class MyView
{
      MyView(int id)
        :this(new MyViewModel(id))
      {
      }

      MyView(MyViewModel viewModel)
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
      }
}

class MyViewModel
{
     private int _id;
     public int ID
     {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id= value; OnPropertyChanged("ID"); }
     }
     public MyViewModel(int id)
     {
        ID=id;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Doctor stated that passing variable to viewmodel is the right way to do it and that assigning the viewmodels parameter is wrong:  Let me comment the following:

What I think is that both ways are wrong.

The first because the viewmodel is in most cases also used as a binding/ datacontext for a view (XAML) page. Which must have a datacontext with no constructor properties/ input vars, even when setting default value like: public MyviewModel(int? InputVar = null){}

The second because assigning values to parameters inside other viewmodel classes makes it horrible because those variables are once set and will become default/ null or empty back when something others is happening in the viewmodel, even when not reassigning or handling that parameter. That's often the problem with my projects, want to send data to other viewmodels the easy way but always having problems with that. I would recommend using EventAggregators: an example:

```
public class EventAggregator
{
    private static readonly EventAggregator instance = new EventAggregator();
    public static EventAggregator Instance => instance;

    private EventAggregator()
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler<ParameterEventArgs> ParameterEvent;

    public void PublishParameter(string parameter)
    {
        ParameterEvent?.Invoke(this, new ParameterEventArgs(parameter));
    }
}

public class ParameterEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ParameterEventArgs(string parameter)
    {
        Parameter = parameter;
    }

    public string Parameter
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

And then in Viewmodel A:

```
public class ViewModelA
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        string parameterValue = "Hello, ViewModelB!";
        EventAggregator.Instance.PublishParameter(parameterValue);
    }
}
```

And in Viewmodel B:

```
public class ViewModelB
{
    public ViewModelB()
    {
        EventAggregator.Instance.ParameterEvent += OnParameterReceived;
    }

    private void OnParameterReceived(object sender, ParameterEventArgs e)
    {
        string parameter = e.Parameter;
        // Now you can use the 'parameter' in ViewModelB.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a solution, just saying why other solution are wrong can be done in the comments.

Comment: have updated my post with a solution and example. At least this works for me